# regex to match only decimals after a colon

Tags: c#, regex

I'm real close but I'm not a regex expert. Here's my input strings.

```
DCIN  : 11.896V
5V    :  4.988V
Vcom  :  0.008V
5VStby:  4.992V
48V   :  0.042V
48I   :    0mA
```

I want only the numeric values after the colon. This is what I have so far

```
/[^\D]+\.?[^\D]+/
```

and it's also grabbing the two 48 instances and it isn't getting the 0

Comment: Only decimals after a colon?  So for the first line, you want `896`?  That's the decimal portion of that number.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(s, @":\s*(\d*\.?\d+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value).ToList()` - if you need to get `11.896`, `4.988`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex requires at least 2 digits on end, that is why it does not match the zero on the last line, and there is no restriction in your pattern to only match after a colon.

Use

```
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @":\s*(\d*\.?\d+)")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Valu‌​e)
     .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3A%5Cs*%28%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%29&i=DCIN%20%20%3A%2011.896V%0D%0A5V%20%20%20%20%3A%20%204.988V%0D%0AVcom%20%20%3A%20%200.008V%0D%0A5VStby%3A%20%204.992V%0D%0A48V%20%20%20%3A%20%200.042V%0D%0A48I%20%20%20%3A%20%20%20%200mA)

**Details**:

- `:\s*` - a colon and zero or more whitespace
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Capturing group 1 holding the value you need:

  - `\d*` - zero or more digits
  - `\.?` - an optional dot
  - `\d+` - one or more digits.

[image]

Comment: Oh so close, I don't want the colon or whitespace after it

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried it out in C, not my RegEx tester and it works a treat!

Comment: The whole point here is to use *capturing*, it is meant to let you access *parts* of matches. It only makes sense to use lookarounds when you need overlapping matches, not the case here. Sure, you may also use `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=:\s*)\d*\.?\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Valu‌​e).ToList();`, but the solution above does it in a more natural way (note that .NET is one of the few regex engines that lets you use `*` and `+` inside lookbehinds).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3A%5Cs*%28%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%29&i=DCIN%20%20%3A%2011.896V%0D%0A5V%20%20%20%20%3A%20%204.988V%0D%0AVcom%20%20%3A%20%200.008V%0D%0A5VStby%3A%20%204.992V%0D%0A48V%20%20%20%3A%20%200.042V%0D%0A48I%20%20%20%3A%20%20%20%200mA)

```
^[^:]*:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)
```